# What changed about the data type of this APL variable after this code (Part two)?

Tags: apl

I am writing a text file from APL. I have a character matrix defined as UMMB in my APL script, which is being used for the body of this text file. I am able to successfully call my .txt document writing function using this variable as the body.

I then run the following code on the matrix, (which basically wraps a few html tags around each element of this array.)

[image]

Now, when I attempt to run this function, it cannot be passed properly into this function.
What changed about the definition of my character matrix due to the code in the screenshot that makes it such that my function now won't accept it as a parameter to be passed?

Note: In both situations (pre and post code,) I am passing the flattened version of the character matrix to the file creation function.

```
⍕UMMB
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you post a screenshot instead of including the source code as text?

Comment: No reason- just easier. I can edit the question to contain the actual code if you'd like.

Comment: That'd be a good idea. Also, if you could tell more about the flavour of APL in use, it'd make it easier to provide good answers.

Comment: How does the error manifest itself? Could you add the error message to your post?

Comment: Are you sure `UMMB` starts as a flat character matrix (how do you know?) and does everything work if you don't modify `UMMB`?

Comment: I am passing the flat character matrix UMMB as the parameter to the file creation function. Everything does work If I don't modify UMMB with the script above.

Comment: You have said nothing about what `UMMB` actually contains. Maybe it is required to have a specific number of rows and/or columns. Could you give some details about its content?

Comment: Yes I will include a screenshot of it's exact contents.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the function in question expects a simple ("flat") character matrix. Try adding the following line at the very end of your script:

```
UMMB←⍕UMMB
```

If this doesn't help, then it help to be provided with the result of the following expressions *before* your script runs:

```
⍴UMMB
≡UMMB
⊃UMMB
```

---

**Hint:** Improved your script with array-orientation:

```
e←⍴UMMB               ⍝ shape of UMMB
UMMB←3/UMMB           ⍝ triplicate every column
i←3×⍳e[2]             ⍝ 3 6 9 ... (3×columns)
UMMB[;¯2+i]←⊂'<td>'   ⍝ amend first of every triplet
UMMB[;i]←⊂'</td>'     ⍝ amend third of every triplet
UMMB←(⊂'<tr>'),k,⊂'</tr>'   ⍝ surround rows
h←'<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>UMMB</title></head><body><table>'
t←'</table></body></html>'
UMMB←⍕3 1⍴h UMMB t
```

(I've also taken the freedom of making the generated HTML valid.)

Comment: The flat character matrix is what I'm already passing in both cases (updated the question to note this.)